# ISP менеджер

Tags: php, isp

Вообщем нужно добавлять при создание нового домена в настройку nginx свои найстройки, руками не очень удобно... Записей много.

Comment: Вы издиваетесь? Я спрашиваю есть ли в ISP возможность генерировать настройки nginx хостов со своими настройками и если есть где? Глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [шаблонами](http://ru.ispdoc.com/index.php/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_(ISPmanager)) конфигурации.